# Apply conditionally an image style on an User Profile page

Tags: 8, media

At the moment the module “[Image Styles Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagestyles_rules)” is only available for drupal 7, is there another  way to apply conditionally an image style depending on the aspect ratio of the image (portrait or landscape) in Drupal 8? Specifically to be applied to the image profile of an user, on his/hers respective profile page.

Comment: TYPO: the module is only available for drupal 7 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This module [auto image style](https://www.drupal.org/project/auto_image_style), is also available for drupal 8.

It describes:

> Allows to apply an image style depending on whether the orientation of original image is portrait or landscape.

So it might be what you want.